# Как сохранить значения переменных после закрытия приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio

У меня в `activity` один из множества элементов- `CheckBox`. При его значении `true` я хочу поменять что-то в другой `activity`. Но после выхода из приложения данные не сохраняются. Как объявлять такие переменные, как boolean, int и их массивы, значения которых будут сохраняться после выхода из приложения?

Comment: смотрите в сторону `Preferences` - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings?hl=ru

Comment: если вы говорите о выходе (например вы неделю туда заглядывать не будете), то пишите данные в базу, и считывайте их оттуда перед запуском экрана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гляньте здесь

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences.html
Структура ключ/значение.

И здесь

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html
Полноценная база данных. Подходит для хранения более структурированных данных.

Так же можно сохранять в файле с помощью реализации Serializable(в сети полно примеров)